# Printer thermistors read completely wrong after changing firmware

Tags: marlin, firmware, creality-cr-10, thermistor

I recently installed Marlin 1.1.9.1 onto my Creality CR-10S. After doing so, the temperatures for both the bed and hotend now read -14 °C. I have changed the setting in the Marlin `configurations.h` to several different thermistors, and it either reads 0 or -14 °C.

I have now installed several different versions of Marlin and with each one I experience the same problem.

Is there some tuning setting that I am missing or has installing the firmware somehow fried something on my board?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, to anyone who is looking at this post, I am an idiot. I have spent the last 4 or more hours sifting through youtube videos and forum posts to figure out this problem. I have reinstalled firmware modifications dozens of times. All of this, to just now discover that I never had the bed or hotend cables connected. That's right, I never even considered the fact that I had yet to plug in those cables after transporting my printer to a new location.

Don't be like me. Check the simplest solutions first.

Comment: MINTEMP! no connection is Mintemp -14!